# Most effective ways to extract Android Cursor (sqlite) into an array to be used in AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: java, android, arrays, performance, sqlite

I want to know the most effective way to extract data from android SQLite Database Cursor into an array.
The problem is when i'm using dialog of list (AlertDialog.Builder.setItems) the items are [set from an array](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28java.lang.CharSequence[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29). To generate the array I need to go through each row of the Cursor and regenerate new array based on the values, and it takes **extremely longer** time to process.

Maybe I’m missing something like c++ std::vector or python's list where i can push/append and pop quickly. And I’m wondering how do people work on their dialog of list which fetch data from database and keep it fast to process. thanks

```
//-- Draw all list of base account
    dbv_accounts = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE type='BASE'",null);
    CharSequence[] accounts_list = {};
    if (dbv_accounts.getCount()>0)
        while (dbv_accounts.moveToNext()) //-- cursor starts from -1
        {
            CharSequence[] new_accountl = new CharSequence[accounts_list.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(accounts_list, 0, new_accountl, 0, accounts_list.length);
            new_accountl[accounts_list.length] = dbv_accounts.getString(dbv_accounts.getColumnIndex("name"));
            accounts_list = new_accountl;
        }
    db.close();
    final CharSequence[] finalAccounts_list = accounts_list;
    bt_Cba_Baseaccount.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChangebaseaccountActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Pick Base Account Name");
                    builder.setItems(
                            finalAccounts_list,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){
                                    bt_Cba_Baseaccount.setText(finalAccounts_list[item]);
                                    String ba = finalAccounts_list[item].toString();
                                }
                            }
                    );
                    builder.show();
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For them looking for the solution, the simple solution is using ArrayList and convert it to an array. It works much faster than generating new array for each row Cursor reading

```
//-- Draw all list of base account
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(getResources().getString(R.string.databasename),MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    Cursor dbv_accounts = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE type='BASE'",null);
    //-- Make ArrayList and push every needed row value
    ArrayList<CharSequence> ALaccounts_list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    while (dbv_accounts.moveToNext())
    {
        String row = dbv_accounts.getString(dbv_accounts.getColumnIndex("name"));
        ALaccounts_list.add(row);
    }
    db.close();
```

then covert the ArrayList to an Array

```
  CharSequence[] accounts_list = new CharSequence[ALaccounts_list.size()];
  accounts_list = ALaccounts_list.toArray(accounts_list);
  final CharSequence[] finalAccounts_list = accounts_list;
```

The array is ready to use in AlertDialog.Builder.setItems